# How to import .obj model to blender with the texture that have multiple material?

Tags: texturing, materials, import, obj

So im newbie on blender and wanted to make an edit or view the 3d model on blender. I can already import the .obj file with File > Import > Wavefront, but it is just the model not the texture. I already switch to render preview but still no texture like this:

[image: [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/QSC2X.jpg]

The model itself has multiple materials like the image from material 1 to material 36 and the folder has a .mtl file which I don't know what the use is for. Here is the image :

[image]

[image]

The texture itself is on atlas texture or baked or I don't know how to call it. There are multiple textures too from accessories, body, leg, head, and hair. I give one example from the accessories part:

[image]

So how do I apply each texture part to the model? I search the same question here and on youtube but it seems there is no topic that is similar to my question.

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/57531/fbx-export-why-there-are-no-materials-or-textures/

Comment: As a newbie it seems that i can't understand the tutorial on that forum sorry, could you give a conclusion or just direct steps for a problem that I have?